# How to get Retrofit error message in android?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

```
 <-- 401 Unauthorized http://172.20.20.128/api/v1/login (126ms)
    D/OkHttp: Date: Tue, 19 Sep 2017 12:55:29 GMT
    D/OkHttp: Server: Apache/2.4.12 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1m PHP/5.5.24 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
    D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.24
    D/OkHttp: Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=bl0brh2n6pr1sbp76kf95q8um1; path=/; HttpOnly
    D/OkHttp: Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
    D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
    D/OkHttp: Pragma: no-cache
    D/OkHttp: Set-Cookie: language=26fb26f386223e2e177900bfa422048f6e2e5367s%3A5%3A%22en_us%22%3B; expires=Thu, 28-Dec-2017 12:55:29 GMT; Max-Age=8640000; path=/
    D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 68
    D/OkHttp: Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
    D/OkHttp: Connection: Keep-Alive
    D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json
    D/OkHttp: {"error":true,"code":"401","message":"Invalid username or password"}
    D/OkHttp: 
    <-- END HTTP (68-byte body)
```

Above is the log showing in android monitor. I want to get following message that is showing in the above Log detail.

```
{"error":true,"code":"401","message":"Invalid username or password"}
```

This is my Request

```
  call.validateUser(request)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Response<LoginResponse>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    AppLog.info("onCompleted", "onCompleted");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    AppLog.info("onError", new Gson().toJson(e));// not coming to onError. 
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Response<LoginResponse> loginResponse) {

                    AppLog.info("code", "" + loginResponse.code()); // returns 401
                    AppLog.info("message", loginResponse.message()); // returns Unauthorized
                    LoginResponse response = loginResponse.body(); // returns null
                    AppLog.info("errorBody", new Gson().toJson(loginResponse.errorBody()));// returns null
                    AppLog.info("headers", new Gson().toJson(loginResponse.headers()));// returns header detail
                    AppLog.info("body", new Gson().toJson(loginResponse.body()));// returns null


                }
            });
```

I checked with onError callback. it is also showing 401 Unauthorized message not the original error message.

Comment: Assuming `LoginResponse` is a custom class that contains `message` field (or annotated with `@SerializedName("message")`), wouldn't just calling `response.getMessage()` be the thing you need?

Comment: its a non 200 status code then you should get the code in onNext as i see in your comment that is because you have `Response<LoginResponse>`

Comment: maybe this post help https://bytes.babbel.com/en/articles/2016-03-16-retrofit2-rxjava-error-handling.html.

Comment: LoginResponse already have filed name "message". Now i annotated with @SerializedName("message"). no use.I think response.getMessage() return message from Response Type, not from LoginResponse Type. # Vucko

Comment: can you log `loginResponse.errorBody()`?

Comment: loginResponse.errorBody() returns null #Raghunandan

Comment: how is that you are log shows this   **: {"error":true,"code":"401","message":"Invalid username or password"}**. can you post a sample url to try?

Comment: before coming to onNext callback retrofit lib printing that log message.

Comment: @AnbarasuChinna just answered. you will get non http status code in `onNext`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154848/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-anbarasu-chinna).

Comment: @AnbarasuChinna any update on this. If you find a solution pls post it.

Answer (score 1):

why could not try onSucess(); onRespose(); onFailure(); so the coud give error of invalid user name or password

```
private final retrofit.Callback loginCallBack = new retrofit.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void success(Object o, Response response) {
            messageUtil.hideProgressDialog();

            UserItem object = (UserItem) o;
            if (object.getUser().get(0).getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("101")) {
                messageUtil.showMessageDialog("Invalid Username & Password");
            } else if ((object.getUser().get(0).getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("100")) && (object.getUser().get(0).getWedding_create().equalsIgnoreCase("1"))) {
                    VPreferences.setPreferanceRetype(LoginActivity.this, object.getUser().get(0).getRetype());
                    VPreferences.setPreferanceWeddingKey(LoginActivity.this, object.getUser().get(0).getWedd_key());
                    VPreferences.setPreferanceEmail(LoginActivity.this, object.getUser().get(0).getEmail());
                    VPreferences.setPreferanceUserName(LoginActivity.this, object.getUser().get(0).getFirst_name());
                    VPreferences.setPreferanceLastName(LoginActivity.this, object.getUser().get(0).getLast_name());
                    VPreferences.setPreferancePSW(LoginActivity.this,object.getUser().get(0).getPassword());
                    VPreferences.setPreferanceBorG(LoginActivity.this, object.getUser().get(0).getType());
                    VPreferences.setIsLogin(LoginActivity.this, true);
                    VPreferences.setPreferanceBothName(LoginActivity.this,object.getUser().get(0).getBoth_name());
                    VPreferences.setPreferenceClientID(LoginActivity.this, object.getUser().get(0).getCid());
                    VPreferences.setPreferanceCoverPhoto(LoginActivity.this,object.getUser().get(0).getWedd_image());
                VPreferences.setPreferanceMobNo(LoginActivity.this,object.getUser().get(0).getPhoneno());
                VPreferences.setPreferanceAccomodation(LoginActivity.this,object.getUser().get(0).getAcco_detail());
                VPreferences.setPreferanceTravel(LoginActivity.this,object.getUser().get(0).getTrans_detail());
                VPreferences.setPreferanceArrivalDate(LoginActivity.this,object.getUser().get(0).getDate_arrival());
                VPreferences.setPreferanceHisWeddingKey(LoginActivity.this,object.getUser().get(0).getWedd_key());
                VPreferences.setPreferanceProfileImg(LoginActivity.this,object.getUser().get(0).getPropic());
                VPreferences.setPreferanceFName(LoginActivity.this,object.getUser().get(0).getFirst_name());

                    startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity_.class));
                }
            else if((object.getUser().get(0).getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("100")) && (object.getUser().get(0).getWedding_create().equalsIgnoreCase("0"))){
                VPreferences.setPreferanceRetype(LoginActivity.this, object.getUser().get(0).getRetype());
                VPreferences.setPreferanceFName(LoginActivity.this,object.getUser().get(0).getFirst_name());
                VPreferences.setPreferanceWeddingKey(LoginActivity.this, object.getUser().get(0).getWedd_key());
                VPreferences.setPreferanceEmail(LoginActivity.this, object.getUser().get(0).getEmail());
                VPreferences.setPreferancePSW(LoginActivity.this,object.getUser().get(0).getPassword());
                VPreferences.setPreferanceUserName(LoginActivity.this, object.getUser().get(0).getFirst_name());
                VPreferences.setPreferanceLastName(LoginActivity.this, object.getUser().get(0).getLast_name());
                VPreferences.setPreferanceBorG(LoginActivity.this, object.getUser().get(0).getType());
                VPreferences.setIsLogin(LoginActivity.this, true);
                VPreferences.setPreferanceProfileImg(LoginActivity.this,object.getUser().get(0).getPropic());
                VPreferences.setPreferanceBothName(LoginActivity.this,object.getUser().get(0).getBoth_name());
                VPreferences.setPreferenceClientID(LoginActivity.this, object.getUser().get(0).getCid());
                VPreferences.setPreferanceCoverPhoto(LoginActivity.this,object.getUser().get(0).getWedd_image());
                VPreferences.setPreferanceHisWeddingKey(LoginActivity.this,object.getUser().get(0).getWedd_key());
                VPreferences.setPreferanceMobNo(LoginActivity.this,object.getUser().get(0).getPhoneno());
                VPreferences.setPreferanceAccomodation(LoginActivity.this,object.getUser().get(0).getAcco_detail());
                VPreferences.setPreferanceTravel(LoginActivity.this,object.getUser().get(0).getTrans_detail());
                VPreferences.setPreferanceArrivalDate(LoginActivity.this,object.getUser().get(0).getDate_arrival());
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ChooseOneActivity_.class));
            }else if((object.getUser().get(0).getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("100")) && (object.getUser().get(0).getRetype().equalsIgnoreCase("0") && (object.getUser().get(0).getWedding_create().equalsIgnoreCase("0")))){
                VPreferences.setPreferanceRetype(LoginActivity.this, object.getUser().get(0).getRetype());
                VPreferences.setPreferanceWeddingKey(LoginActivity.this, object.getUser().get(0).getWedd_key());
                VPreferences.setPreferanceFName(LoginActivity.this,object.getUser().get(0).getFirst_name());
                VPreferences.setPreferanceEmail(LoginActivity.this, object.getUser().get(0).getEmail());
                VPreferences.setPreferanceUserName(LoginActivity.this, object.getUser().get(0).getFirst_name());
                VPreferences.setPreferanceLastName(LoginActivity.this, object.getUser().get(0).getLast_name());
                VPreferences.setPreferancePSW(LoginActivity.this,object.getUser().get(0).getPassword());
                VPreferences.setPreferanceBorG(LoginActivity.this, object.getUser().get(0).getType());
                VPreferences.setIsLogin(LoginActivity.this, true);
                VPreferences.setPreferanceProfileImg(LoginActivity.this,object.getUser().get(0).getPropic());
                VPreferences.setPreferanceBothName(LoginActivity.this,object.getUser().get(0).getBoth_name());
                VPreferences.setPreferenceClientID(LoginActivity.this, object.getUser().get(0).getCid());
                VPreferences.setPreferanceCoverPhoto(LoginActivity.this,object.getUser().get(0).getWedd_image());
                VPreferences.setPreferanceHisWeddingKey(LoginActivity.this,object.getUser().get(0).getWedd_key());
                VPreferences.setPreferanceMobNo(LoginActivity.this,object.getUser().get(0).getPhoneno());
                VPreferences.setPreferanceAccomodation(LoginActivity.this,object.getUser().get(0).getAcco_detail());
                VPreferences.setPreferanceTravel(LoginActivity.this,object.getUser().get(0).getTrans_detail());
                VPreferences.setPreferanceArrivalDate(LoginActivity.this,object.getUser().get(0).getDate_arrival());
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity_.class));
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            messageUtil.showMessageDialog("Server Error !!");
            messageUtil.hideProgressDialog();
        }
    };
```

Comment: If we use retrofit.Callback we can achieve i think. But in case of RxObservable I can not get exact error message.

Comment: @AnbarasuChinna i would like to try can you give me a test url?

Comment: try it on your url no problem my url is not give for security purpose  so

Comment: @OmDave i asked AnbarasuChinna not you.

Answer (score 1):

You have `Observable<Response<LoginResponse>>`.

Quoting jake from https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1218

There are three ways to construct your observable:

```
1. Observable<BodyType>
2. Observable<Response<BodyType>>
3. Observable<Result<BodyType>>
```

> For the first version, there's nowhere to hang non-200 response
>   information so it is included in the exception passed to onError. For
>   the latter two, the data is encapsulated in the Response object and
>   can be accessed by calling errorBody().

You can use `loginResponse.errorBody()` as you can see from https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Response.html#errorBody--

You can log in `onNext` as

```
if(loginResponse.isSuccessfull() {

     // do something
} else {

 AppLog.info("errorbody",listResponse.errorBody().string());

}
```

Note : Before answering I tried a sample api which returned 404 status code. `new Gson().toJson(loginResponse.body())` does return null. I changed to `loginResponse.errorBody().string()` and i was able to log the error body

Answer (score 0):

Go to the LoginResponse.java page and write the code that I have written over here

```
    @SerializedName("message")
public String message;

public String getmessage(){return message;}

@SerializedName("code")
public String code;

public String getcode(){return code;}

@SerializedName("error")
public String error;

public String geterror(){return error;}
```

After you have written this code write the following code in your api response

```
                @Override
            public void onNext(Response<LoginResponse> loginResponse) {

                AppLog.info("code", "" + loginResponse.body().getcode());
                AppLog.info("message", loginResponse.body().getmessage());
                AppLog.info("errorBody", new Gson().toJson(loginResponse..body().geterror()));
                AppLog.info("headers", new Gson().toJson(loginResponse.headers()));
            }
```

Comment: @SerializedName("message")
public String message;

@SerializedName("code")
public String code;

@SerializedName("error")
public String error;  I have created as above. response.body() returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `Interceptor` as shown

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:x.x.x'
```

In your RestClient class add the following

```
private APIInterface service;

public RestClient() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(AppConfiguration.BASEURL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .build();
        service = retrofit.create(APIInterface.class);
    }
```

Check out [this](http://jordifierro.com/android-http-interceptor-testing)  for more details